# How does $ f(x)=\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x-1}}. x \ge1 $ produce a piecewise function with an interval that is a constant fucntion?

Tags: functions, nested-radicals, piecewise-continuity

I found this function in an old math contest.
$$ f(x)=\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x-1}},\space \space x\ge 1 $$
This function is identical to the piecewise function,
$$ g(x) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if $1\le x\le 2$ } \\[2ex]
2\sqrt{x-1}, & \text{if $2\lt x$ }
\end{cases}$$

I have proved the equality between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I would like to understand how the nested radicals produce an interval that is a constant function, and to able to create such functions with tailored characteristics.

Comment: Did you mean this:? Let $y=\sqrt{x-1}, y\ge0$  $$\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x-1}}=|y-1|=?$$

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x-1}}=\sqrt{x-1+1+2\sqrt{x-1}}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{x-1})^2}$...

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Based on the comments of @labbhattacharjee and @JetfiRex, we can rearrange the expression as:
\begin{align*}
f(x) & =\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x-1}}\\\\
& = \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1} - 1)^{2}} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1} + 1)^{2}}\\\\
& = |\sqrt{x - 1} - 1| + |\sqrt{x - 1} + 1|\\\\
& = |\sqrt{x - 1} - 1| + \sqrt{x - 1} + 1
\end{align*}

whenever $x\geq 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes ! I see how the constant portion forms from the sum of the two radicals, thank you. Time to try out making my own similar function.